# PHP divide array based on matching values

Tags: php, arrays, divide

In PHP, is it possible to divide or split an array based on its matching values? These array values are being pushed into the array dynamically. They are the results from a single mysql database query. Long story short, I managed to accomplish this task by putting my query in a for loop and doing some jenky PHP coding but that approach seemed very inefficient and easy to break. The array below is an example of an array I am attempting to divide:

```
$returnedData = [
    ["1003", "correct"],
    ["1003", "incorrect"],
    ["1003", "correct"],
    ["1004", "correct"],
    ["1004", "incorrect"],
    ["1004", "incorrect"],
    ["1005", "incorrect"],
    ["1005", "correct"],
    ["1005", "incorrect"]
  ];
```

Can this array be split up like this using PHP?

```
  $returnedData = [
    [
      ["1003", "correct"],
      ["1003", "incorrect"],
      ["1003", "correct"]
    ],
    [
      ["1004", "correct"],
      ["1004", "incorrect"],
      ["1004", "incorrect"]
    ],
    [
      ["1005", "incorrect"],
      ["1005", "correct"],
      ["1005", "incorrect"]
    ]
  ];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You may find `array_filter` or `array_reduce` helpful.

Comment: I have tried json_encode / json_decode method but wasn't able to get it to work. Most of my attempts resulted in a PHP object that had numbers for key names which I was unable to access despite doing a lot of research on it. I tried more variations than I can list here but after hitting numerous dead ends I decided to ask to see if it was possible. BTW, thank you very much for your response.

Comment: Yeah, the JSON functions aren’t going to be of much use. I’ve included an example using `array_reduce` below and several other people have suggested `foreach` loops. Take your pick.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your time B. Desai!

Answer (score 0):

You can group array by traverse it. Try following code:

```
<?php

$returnedData = [
    ["1003", "correct"],
    ["1003", "incorrect"],
    ["1003", "correct"],
    ["1004", "correct"],
    ["1004", "incorrect"],
    ["1004", "incorrect"],
    ["1005", "incorrect"],
    ["1005", "correct"],
    ["1005", "incorrect"]
  ];

$grouped_array = array();
foreach($returnedData as $data)
{
    if(isset($grouped_array[$data[0]]))
        array_push($grouped_array[$data[0]],$data);
    else
        $grouped_array[$data[0]] = array($data);
}
$grouped_array = array_values($grouped_array);
print_r($grouped_array);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/0uVXe)

Comment: Thanks again B. Desai!  I owe you!  Thank you everybody for your help! This problem has shut down my progress for several days and finally I have a working solution. I can't thank you all enough!

Comment: @coleton_c if answer is helpful then upvote and mark it correct for accept answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Use This code

```
$returnedData2=$log=array();

foreach($returnedData as $i=>$subAry){
    $ind=$subAry[0];
    if(isset($log[$ind])){
       $ind2= $log[$ind];
       array_push($returnedData2[$ind2], $subAry);

    }else{
       $log[$ind]=$i;
       $returnedData2[$i]=array();
       array_push($returnedData2[$i], $subAry);

    }

}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($returnedData2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?php
$returnedData = [
    ["1003", "correct"],
    ["1003", "incorrect"],
    ["1003", "correct"],
    ["1004", "correct"],
    ["1004", "incorrect"],
    ["1004", "incorrect"],
    ["1005", "incorrect"],
    ["1005", "correct"],
    ["1005", "incorrect"]
  ];

$output = array();

foreach($returnedData as $value)
{
    if(isset($output[$value[0]]))
        array_push($output[$value[0]],$value);
    else
        $output[$value[0]] = array($value);
}
$output = array_values($output);

foreach($output as $data){
    print_r(json_encode($data));echo "\n";
}
```

see output here:[output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5ecc46c1bfeaed4eb0e5fc4e0de254e64521f1ae)

Answer (score 0):

you can check this which first format your code then return match key array. i Used **json_encode** for format array result as your requirement

```
<?php

$data = [
    ["1003", "correct"],
    ["1003", "incorrect"],
    ["1003", "correct"],
    ["1004", "correct"],
    ["1004", "incorrect"],
    ["1004", "incorrect"],
    ["1005", "incorrect"],
    ["1005", "correct"],
    ["1005", "incorrect"]
];

$format_data = array();

foreach ($data as $value) {
    if (isset($format_data[$value[0]])) {
        array_push($format_data[$value[0]], $value);
    } else {
        $format_data[$value[0]] = array($value);
    }
}
$format_array = array_values($format_data);

foreach ($format_array as $data) {
    $result[] = json_encode($data);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
?>
```

and final output is :

[image]